# Hit-Testing does not work in WPF Border with lower Z-index

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, z-index, hittest

I have a piece of code with two `Border` elements, but the hit-testing only works for the topmost `Border` (Border2) in the code below. This means that when I right-click, I see the message box, but when I left-click, nothing happens. Is there a way to fix this so that I can capture different mouse events with sibling controls that have different Z-index values? Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="HiTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HiTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:Border1 Background="Transparent"/>
        <local:Border2 Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>


public class Border1 : Border
{
    public Border1()
    {
        MouseLeftButtonDown += Border1_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }

    private void Border1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Left");
    }
}

public class Border2 : Border
{
    public Border2()
    {
        MouseRightButtonDown += Border2_MouseRightButtonDown;
    }

    private void Border2_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right");
    }
}
```

In summary, I want to be able to capture different mouse events with sibling controls that have different Z-index values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to capture events for sibling elements. Bubbling  only works for elements with parent and child relation.

Something like this with parent child relation.

```
<Grid Name="Parent">
    <Border Name="Border01" Background="Transparent" MouseDown="Border01_MouseDown">
        <Border Name="Border02" Background="Transparent" MouseDown="Border01_MouseDown" />
    </Border>
</Grid>

private void Border01_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Grid)) { }

        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(Border))
        {
            if (((Border)sender).Name == "Border01" & e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Left & Button01");
            }
            if (((Border)sender).Name == "Border02" & e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Right  & Button02");
            }
        }
    }
```

If you have sibling elements you need to delegate the MouseDown from the top element to the lower element by yourself.